# Persisting third-party classes with no ID's

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Say I have the following Java class, which is owned by a vendor so I can't change it:

```
public class Entry {
    private String user;
    private String city;

    // ...
    // About 10 other fields
    // ...

    // Getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I would like to persist it to a table, using JPA 2.0 (OpenJPA implementation). I cannot annotate this class (as it is not mine), so I'm using `orm.xml` to do that.

I'm creating a table containing a column per field, plus another column called `ID`. Then, I'm creating a sequence for it.

My question is: is it at all possible to tell JPA that the ID that I would like to use for this entity doesn't even exist as a member attribute in the `Entry` class? How do I go about creating a JPA entity that will allow me to persist instances of this class?

**EDIT**

I am aware of the strategy of extending the class and adding an ID property it. However, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve extending this class, because I need this solution to also be applicable for the case when it's not only one class that I have to persist, but a collection of interlinked classes - none of which has any ID property. In such a scenario, extending doesn't work out.

Comment: I think creating an `EntryWithID extends Entry` should work. The only thing you will add there is a new property ID.

Comment: Right, but that would work only if we're talking about one class that I'd like to persist. What if I have a graph of objects linked with each other? I should update my question...

Comment: Don't try to persist arbitrary classes, not designed to be persisted. Design your database, then design JPA entities mapped to the database, and transform the graph of objects into a graph of JPA entities. An ID is mandatory in JPA entities.

Comment: DataNucleus JPA has support for "datastore identity" (a surrogate id where you don't need to have a field in the class). A vendor extension to JPA. Likely OpenJPA doesn't support that, but it is one way forward

Comment: @JBNizet your comment makes sense, but I am not sure what prompts you to state that such an object isn't "designed to be persisted". What makes an object "designed to be persisted"?

Comment: Actually OpenJPA (since it originated as a JDO provider) does support "datastore id". Look at https://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/1.0.x/manual/ref_guide_pc_oid.html

Comment: It is designed to be persisted using JPA if it follows the JPA rules: an ID field is present, it uses basic collection interfaces only, it is mappable, in a sane way, to a relational schema, etc. Moreover, relying on externally-defined classes, whose implementation and interfaces might change over time, to define your database schema, i quite a hazardous thing to do, IMO.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, the argument about external classes changing over time indeed makes sense, but for certain reasons this argument doesn't hold for the particular scenario I'm facing (in a nutshell: it's a given that these classes will never change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up doing the following:

```
public class EntryWrapper {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    private Entry entry;
}
```

So, I am indeed wrapping the entity but differently from the way that had been suggested. As the `Entry` class is vendor-provided, I did all its ORM work in an `orm.xml` file. When persisting, I persist `EntryWrapper`.

Comment: Hi. Would you mind sharing how you implement this solution or the resource you referred to, if any? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with JPA, but I wouldn't extend your base classes, instead I would wrap them:

```
public class PersistMe<T> {

  @Id
  private long id;

  private T objToWrap;

  public(T objToWrap) {
    this.objToWrap = objToWrap;
  }
}
```

I can't test it, if it doesn't work let me know so I can delete the answer.